# How can a web site be accessed without A, AAAA or CNAME records?

Tags: domain-name-system

Someone who was helping me setup an Apache server on a VPS said that I can set up my DNS in such a way that you can't resolve the IP by `ping`ing the hostname because apparently the ping tool only queries for A/AAAA/CNAME records.

He said his method of doing this was to create an obfuscated port, say 2673 or some such, and create an SRV record which links to this. And the only way to get the IP of the server is by digging through raw DNS data. He showed me an example of one of his sites, and sure enough, I was unable to ping for IP, and when using nmap intense scan, I was unable to get any meaningful results on portscan or what the server was, but yet I could visit it in Firefox.

Anyone know how he did this? And how I might be able to replicate this for my domain names? And finally, if this is the way to do it, how exactly it works (technical point of view)?

Comment: Would you care to share this example?

Comment: 1. Being able to ping the server ip address has nothing to do with DNS. 2. Unless I'm missing something, I'm not aware of any web browser that supports SRV records so I don't see how what you've stated is possible.

Comment: I can't find his example offhand as it was on skype, and don't see what the deal with hold is? Has MR/Mrs moderator considered for a second that not being able to ping a DNS would be great for a company, as it reduces the  risk of hackers/DDoSers? That's why i am wanting to do it. And no, i was't pining the IP of the server, it was like ping [domain name] when it resolves the IP. And if SRV records would not work, is there any other DNS record anyone knows that might obfuscate it?

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a traditional forum and many things work much differently here. For instance, your question was closed by regular members of the community who took issue with a previous revision of the question. I (an actual moderator; we have diamonds next to our names) saw some potential in the question, so I edited it and reopened it. You can learn more about how the site works by checking the help link at the top of every page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is theoretically possible. There have been multiple proposals on how to locate HTTP sites with [SRV records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), the most well known of which is [RFC 2782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782). Indeed, many other services already use SRV records in similar ways.

An example SRV record that might locate an HTTP service for `example.com` running on port 2673 might look like:

```
_http._tcp.example.com. IN      SRV     0 5 2673 webserver.example.com.
```

This, of course, must have a corresponding record to locate the real `webserver`:

```
webserver.example.com.  IN      A       198.51.100.39
```

The problem is that none of these proposals have gotten any real traction, and to the best of my knowledge, most browsers don't even implement this. Until today, the last I'd heard was that *no* web browser implemented it. Even [Mozilla's own bug tracker shows it as unimplemented in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14328), so I'm not really sure what your friend demonstrated.

So you have two negatives with this approach:

First, most people won't be able to view your web site if you don't have address records and only rely on the SRV record proposal.

Second, it won't really protect you from any but the most idiotic of morons, as it's quite trivial to query the DNS and locate your server's actual IP address, and using only a SRV record makes it only slightly less trivial; you have to do two lookups instead of one. Big hairy deal.

Comment: Just to reiterate, hiding your IP Address will do nothing for your security (Security through Obscurity isn't). Two main reasons: 1, there are plenty of people running blind scans against ranges of IP addresses - sooner or later they'll find yours and run their automated tools against it. 2, if you're offering any kind of public service, then you have to publish some kind of information to allow Joe Public to access your service. Even *if* there was a way to "hide" your IP in DNS, someone could just use the DNS record without caring what the IP is.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the enlightening answer. I would have been surprised if it was plausible, as more people would be doing it if so. And both on my private servers where i test, and my company ones, we do rely on active security, i just thought it might be a useful layer, as most DDoSers are not particularly bright.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a private site, you can access it simply using the IP address. But if the site is on an Apache virtual domain, say www.example.secret then the browser needs to use the URL http://www.example.secret or Apache will not allow it into the site.

The trick is for every member of this private site to add the IP address of www.example.secret to their hosts file.

But if you are doing something illegal, the NSA knows about this trick and it would be easy for them to identify web servers with non-existent domain names so that they can tap into all your traffic.

This ability is mostly useful to those of us who have to set up QA/Acceptance testing servers and access them with the real production host name.

Comment: Apache works just fine with IP addresses and nothing you describe is a trick to any remotely competent engineer.